# An inequality about average

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

If $f$ on $\mathbf{R}^n$is integrable,we define two operators as following.
$$Mf(x)=\underset{r>0}{\sup}\dfrac{1}{\lvert B_r\rvert}\int_{B_r}\lvert f(x-y)\rvert\, dy,\enspace B_r:=\{x|\,\lvert x\rvert\le r\}$$
$$M'f(x)=\underset{r>0}{\sup}\dfrac{1}{(2r)^n}\int_{Q_r}\lvert f(x-y)\rvert\, dy,\enspace Q_r:=[-r,r]^n$$
When $n=1$,$M$ and $M'$ coincide.However,if $n>1$,my question is why there exist constant $c_n$ and $C_n$,depending only on $n$,such that 
$$c_nM'f(x)\le Mf(x)\le C_n M'f(x)$$
It seems obviously,but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: That $B_r \subset Q_r$ is evident. Can you show  there exists $\alpha > 0$ satisfying $Q_r \subset B_{\alpha r}$ for all $r > 0$?

Comment: $$Mf(x)\leq M'f(x)\leq 2^n Mf(x).$$

Comment: Thank you very much.Now I understand what sucked me.